# Тавтологии и плеоназмы

Tags: тавтология, плеоназм

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить, к какой из двух групп (тавтологии и плеоназмы) отнести следующие словосочетания:

1) польза от использования
2) объединенный союз
3) на сегодняшний день
4) памятный сувенир
5) свободная вакансия
6) соединить воедино
7) опытный эксперт

Answer (score 3):

Тавтология:  польза от использования,  соединить воедино.

Плеоназм: объединенный союз **(СОЮЗ, -а; м. 1. Тесное соединение, связь (отдельных лиц, групп, классов и т.п.2. Объединение, соглашение для каких-л. совместных целей, действий).** **2.** *памятный сувенир*, *свободная вакансия,* *опытный эксперт*

Выражение **"на сегодняшний день"** уже не является плеонастичным. Оно зафиксировано в Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова.

Вот что говорит Грамота.ру.

> Сочетание **сегодняшний день,** изначально плеонастичное, уже вошло в литературный язык и нарушением нормы не является. Например, «Большой толковый словарь русского языка» под ред. С. А. Кузнецова фиксирует: **На сегодняшний день (в настоящий момент).** *Жить сегодняшним днём (не думая о будущем).* Выражение **на сегодня** вместо **на сегодняшний день,** конечно, тоже можно использовать.

Comment: На сервисе проверки этого задания выдало ошибку. Что-то неправильно...

Comment: Это выражение уже вошло в литературный язык, и считать его ошибочным уже нельзя. Оно зафиксировано в таких известных словарях, как: Толоковый словарь Ожегова, Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Comment: Ошибка на сервисе проверки.