# "Тавтология" и "плеоназм" во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология, множественное-число

Увидел вопрос с заголовком "Тавтологии и плеоназмы" ([Тавтологии и плеоназмы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434470/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b)) и задумался: уместно ли употреблять эти слова во множественном числе? Формально мн. ч. для этих слов существует, но не могу придумать пример его корректного применения.

Дополнение. К моему удивлению, в Нацкорпусе нашлись "тавтологии" (во мн.ч.). Похоже, слово "тавтология" может употребляется в смысле "тавтологическое высказывание", тогда "тавтологии" это "тавтологические высказывания". Правильно ли это?.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Ведь «казус» это и есть случай? Но я не боюсь **тавтологий**. Что бы ни случилось, всегда получится случай. [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

По определению Карнапа, все априорные элементы науки, прежде всего математики, являются **тавтологиями** и аналитическими предложениями, которые ничего не говорят нам о действительности. [С. С. Неретина, А. П. Огурцов. Пути к универсалиям. Раздел V. Универсалии как кванторы: от номинализма к концептуализму (2006)]

«…**тавтологии** возникают в той области, в которой нет причин, оснований. [В. А. Подорога. Проект и опыт (2004)]

Это и есть онтологические равенства, или **тавтологии**. [В. А. Подорога. Проект и опыт (2004)]

Мы не можем отделить предмет суждения от субъекта суждения, и это «я» обнаруживает в себе тавтологию всех **тавтологий** или точку или точку точек интенсивностей. [В. А. Подорога. Проект и опыт (2004)]

отчего-то оказывается не вопросом, а просьбой, а **тавтологии** типа Boys are boys осмысленны. [Е. В. Рахилина. Когнитивная семантика: История. Персоналии. Идеи. Результаты (1999)]

Comment: @shampar  Это заголовок вопроса (я добавил ссылку)

Comment: Объектом лексической правки должны быть также употребленные без стилистического задания
     ***п л е о н а з м ы*** (обороты речи, содержащие однозначные и, тем самым, обычно лишние слова) и
     ***т а в т о л о г и и*** (повторение сказанного близкими по смыслу словами, часто однокоренными), а также многословие. ( ***Справочник по правописанию и стилистике).***

Comment: Здесь (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/56.htm) Розенталь ипользует только единственное число, а здесь (http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxv.html#sect141) – только множственное (?!)

Comment: @ М_Г, насколько мне известно, это один и тот же справочник. Может, редакторы вмешались?